Webpack Alias Not Resolving Import
i want to integrate something from another repo using webpack 5 module federation.... but i have an issue where it isnt resolving alias.
my config is like the following:
module.exports = {
...
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.jsx'],
        alias: {
          "@app": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
          "@pages": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/pages"),
          "@components": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/components"),
          "@core": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/core"),
          "@layouts": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/layouts"),
        },
    },
...
}

but i get many errors like the following, but i see the file is there:
ERROR in ./src/App.tsx 2:0-54
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@app/DeviceWrapper.js' in '/workspaces/mestastic/src'

i have a PR with various things i have tried to get it to work, but now, im out of ideas.
https://github.com/positive-intentions/mestastic/pull/1/files
